# Notification in Jelly Bean not showing

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm trying to create a JB notification, but I can't make it show and it doesn't give any error in the logcat, just it doesn't do anything.

The code I'm using to create notification is the following

```
private void bigPictureNotification(){

    Notification.Builder builder;
    Notification notification;
    NotificationManager manager;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationPendingIntent.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    //carica l'immagine
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.androidworld);

    builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setContentTitle("Titolo piccolo");
    builder.setContentText("Testo della notifica");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notifica);
    builder.setLargeIcon(icon);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_search, "Cerca", pendingIntent);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_stat_notifica, "AndroidWorld", pendingIntent);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Launcher", pendingIntent);
    builder.build();

    notification = new Notification.BigPictureStyle(builder).bigPicture(icon).build();
    //notification = builder.build();
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, notification);

}
```

Where is the mistake?
Thanks for the help

Comment: once see this: http://www.droid-life.com/2012/08/28/how-to-disable-application-notifications-in-jelly-bean-beginners-guide/

Comment: you might have disabled notifications in your phone

Comment: No, tested out as the first thing, but they are showing

Answer (score 0):

Try and add `builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);` before `builder.build();` Worked for me after I put that in.

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove the call to

```
builder.build()
```

just before

```
notification = ...
```

as builder.build() gives you a notification object. Give that a shot.